# Find a function that satisfies certain conditions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to find a function with certain conditions?

$$x \gt 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \gt 0$$
$$x = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0$$
$$f'(1)+f'(6)=a \ne 0$$
$$f'(2)+f'(5)=0$$
$$f'(3)+f'(4)=0$$
$$f'(1) \ne 0$$
$$f'(2) \ne 0$$
$$f'(3) \ne 0$$
$$f'(4) \ne 0$$
$$f'(5) \ne 0$$
$$f'(6) \ne 0$$

I don't care how function behaves when $x<0$.

The function as well as its derivative should be continuous.

Possibly, there is some approach to build such function.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the number of places where you want your derivative to be something specific finite or infinite? And do you care what happens for $x<0$?

Comment: I don't get what you mean to say by "....." . Does it mean that $f'(4)=f'(5)=f'(6)=.....=b$ or $f'(2)=f'(3)=b,  f'(4)=f'(5)=c,  f'(6)=f'(7)=d$ . I mean does there occur to be a series somewhere within?

Comment: @Arthur Number of place is finite. I don't care when x < 0.

Comment: @Manthanein, made a typo. f'(1)=a, f'(2)=b, f'(3)=c, f'(4)=d....

Comment: Please indicate the exact $x$-interval where $f$ should be defined and  $\geq0$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Done.

Comment: I constructed your function (see answer below) with an even better condition, since it is smooth.

Comment: New function (following you **last edit**), see answer below verifying your new conditions. (what will be the next change?)

Comment: What is $a$? Is it $a>0$?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Any constant.

Answer (score 2):

There is a construction of a **smooth** function verifying exactly your conditions :

> **Lemma 1**
>   Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists a smooth function $g_{\varepsilon}$ such that $$  
> g_{\varepsilon}(x)\left\{ 
> \begin{aligned} 
> =1 &\quad  \text{if} \quad  x\leq 0\\
> \in (0,1)&\quad  \text{if} \quad  x\in (0,\varepsilon) \\
> =0 & \quad  \text{if} \quad  x\in [\varepsilon,+\infty)
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> $$

**Proof :**

Let $$h(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
0 &\quad  \text{if} \quad  x\leq 0\\
e^{-\frac1x} & \quad  \text{if} \quad  x>0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Then $h$ is a smooth function (proof by induction on $n$ over $h^{(n)}$) strictly increasing for $x>0$.

It is sufficient to define 
$$ g_{\varepsilon}(x):=\frac{h(h(\varepsilon)-h(x))}{h(h(\varepsilon))}. $$

> **Remark:** $g_{\varepsilon}$ is a smooth approximation of $1_{(-\infty,0]}$.

$ $

> **Lemma 2**
>   For all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, There exists a smooth function $f_{a,b;\varepsilon}$ such that 
>   $$f_{a,b;\varepsilon}(x)\left\{ 
> \begin{aligned} 
> =1 &\quad  \text{if} \quad  x\in [a,b]\\
> \in (0,1)&\quad  \text{if} \quad  x\in (a-\varepsilon,a)\cup (b,b+\varepsilon) \\
> =0 & \quad  \text{if} \quad  x\in (-\infty,a-\varepsilon]\cup [b+\varepsilon,+\infty)
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> $$

**Proof :**

Let $g_{\varepsilon}$ define as in Lemma 1. We just have to define
$$ f_{a,b;\varepsilon}:= g_{\varepsilon}(-x+a)\times g_{\varepsilon}(x-b)$$

> **Remark:** $f_{a,b;\varepsilon}$ is a smooth approximation of $1_{[a,b]}$.

**Main function (for the original question)**

$$\boxed{ f(x):=(2|a| +ax)f_{\frac{1}{4}, \frac32+\frac14;\frac14}(x)+f_{\frac{3}{2}, \frac52;\frac14}(x) +f_{\frac{5}{2}, \frac72;\frac14}(x) +  f_{\frac{7}{2}, \frac92;\frac14}(x)+  f_{\frac{9}{2}, \frac{11}2;\frac14}(x)+  f_{\frac{11}{2}, \frac{13}2;\frac14}(x)+  g_{\frac14}(-(x-\tfrac{13}2))}$$

Since in particular $f'(1)=a$, $f'(2)=f'(3)=f'(4)=f'(5)=f'(6)=0\ $ and $f(0)=0$, and $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, you will have indeed
$$x \gt 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \gt 0$$
$$x = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0$$
$$f'(1)+f'(6)=a \ne 0$$
$$f'(2)+f'(5)=0$$
$$f'(3)+f'(4)=0$$

**Main function (for the actual edited question)**

$$\boxed{ 
\begin{align*}
f(x):=& \Big(|a|+\frac{a}{2}x\Big)f_{\frac{1}{4}, \frac32+\frac14;\frac14}(x)+(6-x)f_{\frac{3}{2}, \frac52;\frac14}(x)  +(6-x)f_{\frac{5}{2}, \frac72;\frac14}(x)+ xf_{\frac{7}{2}, \frac92;\frac14}(x) \\
&+  xf_{\frac{9}{2}, \frac{11}2;\frac14}(x)+  \Big(6|a|+\frac{a}{2}x\Big)f_{\frac{11}{2}, \frac{13}2;\frac14}(x)+  g_{\frac14}(-(x-\tfrac{13}2))
\end{align*}
}
$$
Which is a smooth function verifying (since $f'(1)=f'(6)=\frac{a}2$, $f'(2)=f'(3)=-1$,  $f'(4)=f'(5)=1$, and we still have $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$)   all the following 
$$x \gt 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \gt 0$$
$$x = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0$$
$$f'(1)+f'(6)=a \ne 0$$
$$f'(2)+f'(5)=0$$
$$f'(3)+f'(4)=0$$
$$f'(1) \ne 0$$
$$f'(2) \ne 0$$
$$f'(3) \ne 0$$
$$f'(4) \ne 0$$
$$f'(5) \ne 0$$
$$f'(6) \ne 0$$

Is that good for you?

Answer (score 1):

(The following refers to the state of the question on 03/10/18, 15:00 MEZ.)

We shall first construct the function $g(x):=f'(x)$, whereby we have to distinguish the two cases  (i) $a>0$, (ii) $a<0$. The "provisional" functions
$$\eqalign{h_1(x)&:=(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5),\cr
h_2(x)&:=(x-2/3)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-19/3)\cr}$$
are symmetric with respect to the vertical $x=3.5$; furthermore $$h_i(2)=h_i(3)=h_i(4)=h_i(5)=0\qquad(1\leq i\leq 2)\ ,$$ 
$$h_1(1)=h_1(6)>0,\quad h_2(1)=h_2(6)<0\ ,$$
see the following figure.

[image]

It follows that the functions
$$\eqalign{g_1(x)&:=h_1(x)+10(x-3.5)\cr g_2(x)&:=h_2(x)+10(x-3.5)\cr}$$
satisfy
$$g_i(2)=-g_i(5)\ne0,\quad g_i(3)=-g_i(4)\ne0,\quad g_1(1)+g_1(6)>0, \quad g_2(1)+g_2(6)<0\ .$$
For both $g_i$s the function
$$f(x):=\int_0^x g_i(t)\>dt$$
satisfies all requirements apart from $f'(1)+f'(6)=a$ for the given $a$. Select the proper $g_i$ according to the sign of $a$ and scale the resulting $f$ by the proper *positive* factor in order fulfill  this last condition as well. The resulting $f$s then look as follows:

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have not noticed that the conditions $f'(1)\not=0,f'(2)\not=0,\cdots ,f'(6)\not=0$ are added.

Comment: @mathlove yes, the OP seems to modify his question quite often without warning anyone...

Answer (score 1):

**LAGRANGE INTERPOLALTION POLYNOMIALS**

---

SYNTHESIS OF DERIVATIVE

Let
$$d(x) = f'(x).\tag1$$
Using Lagrange interpolation polynomials of $5th$ order with the table
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x=&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
d_5(x)=&a/2&b&c&-c&-b&a/2\\
\end{pmatrix},\tag2
$$
where $a\not=0,\ b\not=0,c\not=0,$ one can get

$$d_5(x) = \dfrac{(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)}{(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)(1-5)(1-6)}\dfrac a2$$
$$+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)}{(2-1)(2-3)(2-4)(2-5)(2-6)}b$$
$$+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)}{(3-1)(3-2)(3-4)(3-5)(3-6)}c$$
$$+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)(x-6)}{(4-1)(4-2)(4-3)(4-5)(4-6)}(-c)$$
$$+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-6)}{(5-1)(5-2)(5-3)(5-4)(5-6)}(-b)$$
$$+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)}{(6-1)(6-2)(6-3)(6-4)(6-5)}\dfrac a2,$$
$$48d_5(x,a,b,c) = (4b-8c)x^5 + (a-70b+140c)x^4+(-14a+464b-912c)x^3 + (71a-1442b+2716c)x^2+(-154a+2052b-3616c)x +120a-1008b+1680c\tag3,$$

---

ANALYSIS OF THE CONDITIONS

Integration of $(3)$ gives $f(t)$ in the form of
$$f_5(x,a,b,c) = \int_0^xd_5(t,a,b,c)dt = \dfrac x{1440}g_5(x,a,b,c),$$
$$g_5(x,a,b,c) = (20b-40c)x^5+(6a-420b+840c)x^4+(-105a+3480b-6840c)x^3+(710a-14420b+27160c)x^2 +(-2310a+30780b-54240c)x + (3600a-30240b+50400c).$$

The issue condition 
$$x>0 \Rightarrow f(x)>0\tag4$$
can be satisfied only for the non-negative elder coefficient, so
$$(b > 2c) \vee ((b=2c) \wedge (a>0)).\tag5$$

Then, must be $g_5(0)>0.$
Note that both of the conditions $d5(0,a,b,c) \ge 0$ and $g_5(0,a,b,c) \ge 0$
reqires
$$5a - 42b+70c \ge 0,\tag6,$$
and $(5),(6)$ allow the simple solution
$$a>0,\ b=2c \Rightarrow b=\dfrac57a,\ c= \dfrac5{14}a.$$
wherein
$$\boxed{f(x,a) = a(x^2 (2130 + 770 x - 435 x^2 + 42 x^3))/10080}\tag7$$
**satisfies to the all issue conditions in the case** $\mathbf{a>0}$
([see also Wolfram Alpha Plots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7By,%20dy%2Fdx%7D,%20where%20y%3Dx%5E2%2F10080(42x%5E3-435x%5E2%2B770x%2B2130)) for $f(x,1),\ f'_x(x,1)$).

[image: Function and derivation]

There are a lot of another solutions for $a>0.$
All of them must satisfy constraints $(5),(6)$ and [additional control of the abscissa crossing.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20int_0%5Et%20%2014((x(x-7)%2B11)%5E2-1)%2F48%2B((x(x-7)%2B6)(2x-7)%2F24)%7B%7B1,12%7D,%7B-2,-20%7D%7D.%7Bx(x-7),1%7D.%7B%7B7,%2010,%2025%2F2,%20-25%2F2%7D,%7B7%2F2,%205,%2013%2F2,%20-13%2F2%7D%7D%20dx%20where%20t%20in%20(0.,7.0))
Parameter $a=10$ given as the constant and parameters $b, c$ as the columns of the matrix.

---

CASE $\mathbf{a<0}.$

Using Lagrange interpolation polynomials of $6th$ order with the table
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x=&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
h(x)=&1&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\tag8
$$
one can get
$$h(x) = \dfrac{(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)}{(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)(1-5)(1-6)}$$
$$+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)}{(6-1)(6-2)(6-3)(6-4)(6-5)},$$
$$h(x) = \dfrac1{24}(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5).$$
Then the function
$$\boxed{f(x, -|a|) = f(x,|a|) + 2|a|\int_0^x h^2(x)\,dx}$$
**satisfies to the all issue conditions in the case** $\mathbf{a<0}.$

Easy to see that Lagrange interpolation polynomials allow to choose various forms of solutions due to the parameters $b,c$ for the given $a$.

At the same time, the interpolation task allows another effective models, as the trig model
$$f(x) = \dfrac a2x - \dfrac5{2\pi} \sum_{k=1}^4 c_k \sin \dfrac{\pi k}5x,$$
or the cubic splines.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is really helpful. How do you choose values of a,b and c?

Comment: @AndrewFount I am doing more strict analytic and planning to finish in time.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AndrewFount The final edition (simple solution in the case $a<0$)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is entirely possible.

What we need is a cubic-like function starting at $(0,0)$, which has a local maximum turning point at $x\in(1,2)$, a local minimum turning point at $x\in(3,4)$ above the $x$-axis and increasing after that.

This is so that

- the function starts at the origin
- the function is always above $0$ when $x>0$
- there are no turning points at $x=1,\cdots,6$ so each of $f'(x)\neq0$ is fulfilled
- the function is increasing at $x=1$ and $x=6$ so $f'(1)+f'(6)\neq0$.
- the function is increasing at $x=2$ and decreasing at $x=5$ so **given the slopes are the same**, we have $f'(2)+f'(5)=0$
- the function is decreasing at $x=4$ and increasing at $x=5$ so **given the slopes are the same**, we have $f'(3)+f'(4)=0$

> A function that satisfies all but one condition is $$f(x)=x\left(x-7+\frac{\sqrt{46}}2\right)^2$$ The only flaw is that $f'(2)+f'(5)=12\neq0$. For a visualisation see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/brm46tlbyq).

However, I'm sure that there are many other more complicated functions out there that satisfy this criterion as well.

Comment: It seems that $f'(1)+f'(6)=a \ne 0$ is not the same as $f'(1)+f'(6)\ne 0$.

Comment: Why? What is $a$?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but it seems that $a$ is a given non-zero real number which can be negative.

Comment: Well we have that both $f'(1)$ and $f'(6)$ are positive, so $a>0$. Why do you say that $$f'(1)+f'(6)=a \ne 0\not\implies f'(1)+f'(6)\ne 0$$

Comment: One of the conditions we are given is $f'(1)+f'(6)=a\not=0$, not $f'(1)+f'(6)\not=0$. So, your example might work if $a$ is positive, but it seems that we have to consider the cases where $a$ is negative.

Comment: Thanks. I have asked OP.

Answer (score 0):

(The following applies to the state of the question as of March $12$, $2018$; $11$ am UTC-$6$.)

I'm gonna start with $$g(x)=0.02x^2\big((x-3.5)^2+0.2\big)(7-x)^2.$$ The leading coefficient $0.02$ is just so that $g$ isn't that big on $[0,7]$, while the $+0.2$ in the middle is so that $g(3.5)>0$. Function $g$ is continuous, smooth and symmetrical at $x=3.5$ . However, $g$ is not perfect, since $g'(1)+g'(6)=0$ and $g(7)=0$. As a workabout, I will add to $g$ two gaussian functions that shall act as somewhat-continuous indicator functions, namely $$\exp\left(-\frac{(x-1.1)^2}{0.01}\right) +\exp\left(-\frac{(x-7)^2}{0.01}\right).$$ The first gaussian is for breaking the symmetry around $x=1$; the choice of $1.1$ (which is the peak of the gaussian) is so that the slope at $x=1$ is positive (the slope at the peak is zero). The second gaussian is just for ensuring positiveness around $x=7$. Lastly, I propose this function: $$f(x)= \exp\left(-\frac{(x-1.1)^2}{0.01}\right) +\exp\left(-\frac{(x-7)^2}{0.01}\right) +0.02x^2\big((x-3.5)^2+0.2\big)(7-x)^2.$$ Remarks: $f'(1)+f'(6)\approx 7.3576$ and $f(7)>0$; also, $f$ satisfies most of the OP's desired properties ($a$ who?), specially the part where we don't care how $f$ is for $x<0$. ;-)